# Ways to limit interaction volume in a SEM without changing e-beam energy (spot size)

Tags: electrons, microscopy, imaging

All I can find online is that the interaction volume of a scanning electron microscope is affected by e-beam energy, angle of penetration, and sample composition. Are those really the only things that affect it?

I'm trying to shrink my interaction volume as much as I can without changing the e-beam energy. Would changing the spot size do it?  Or anything else, for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct. The beam energy and the specimen's physical properties determine the interaction volume. You can simulate all of this in Rene Gauvin's excellent CASINO Montecarlo programme. 
 [CASINO](http://www.gel.usherbrooke.ca/casino/)

The spot size only changes current by placing different sized apertures on the optic axis. So your interaction volume goes unchanged, you just fill it faster with larger beam currents.

A useful trick is to **reduce the thickness of the specimen**, i.e. the actual volume the beam can interact with. This is one of the (many) reasons why TEM has better resolution than SEM.